# How to code checkbox checked/unchecked behavior in d3.js

Tags: javascript, checkbox, d3.js

I am making a scatterplot using D3. I have the following function that allows the user to filter out certain points using a checkbox:

```
    //un-optimized code, works fine
    d3.selectAll("[name=v]").on("change", function() {
        var selected = this.value;
        display = this.checked ? "inline" : "none";

    svg.selectAll(".dot")
        .filter(function(d) {return selected == d.holidays;}) //returns 1 or 0
        .attr("display", display);
        });
```

This function uses the `"display"` attribute to display the points. However I have a good number of points on the chart, and displaying the points again after un-checking and re-checking takes time on slower machines.

I am attempting to optimize it by changing the opacity to 0 when un-checked and vice versa. However I am relatively new to D3 and cannot figure out how to make this work.

Here is what I have currently. This code works partially - the checkbox is checked by default, and when the user un-checks it, the selected datapoints becomes transparent. However, any subsequent checks/unchecks do not do anything - the code simply instructs the browser to keep changing the opacity to 0.

```
    d3.selectAll("[name=v]").on("change", function() {
        var selected = this.value;
        display = this.checked ? "inline" : "none";

    svg.selectAll(".dot")
        .filter(function(d) {return selected == d.holWkend;})
        .style("opacity", 0);
        });
```

So the above code makes the selected points invisible when the checkbox is unchecked. **What am I missing in order to change the opacity of the selected points to 1 again when the checkbox is re-checked?**

Here is the corresponding checkbox HTML code for reference (includes some custom CSS checkbox styling)

```
   <input type="checkbox" id="switch-id" name="v" value="0" checked>
   <label for="switch-id">Holiday</label>
   <span class="fh-switch-knob"></span>

   <input type="checkbox" id="switch-id" name="v" value="0" checked>
   <label for="switch-id">Non-holiday</label>
   <span class="fh-switch-knob"></span>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is use exactly the same code you have for `display` to set `opacity`:

```
d3.selectAll("[name=v]").on("change", function() {
    var selected = this.value;
    opacity = this.checked ? 1 : 0;

svg.selectAll(".dot")
    .filter(function(d) {return selected == d.holWkend;})
    .style("opacity", opacity);
    });
```

Comment: ...I somehow forgot about the display = this.checked? line. I tried something like this but since I forgot to change display to opacity I thought it was the wrong syntax. Thanks!